# To remove or delete particular character by giving their range in a specified column using awk, sed or perl

Tags: regex, perl, awk, sed, text-processing

I need to remove the particular characters from only 1st column "`_p1.pdb_________________`" (example: to specify the range like 5 to 10 charter, from middle of the column 3) .  I tried this command 
`sed 's/_p.*//' test` but it will delete all the things starting from _p. I have to remove for 38690797 line. So can anyone give efficient command to do this?

I had checked all the previous questions, nothing gave exactly what I need.

Sample Input file:

```
    EAZ51036_p1.pdb_________________ SSPP00000432782.1_1_p1.pdb______ 0.834183 0.812304    11175    11476     9322
    BBX51096_p1.pdb_________________ EEEP00000435284.1_1_p1.pdb______ 0.834183 0.812304    11175    11476     9322
    CCZ58032_5j3b_p3.pdb____________ NNNP00000343764.6_192_p1.pdb____ NULL____ NULL____ ________ ________ ________
    WWW25032_5j3b_p6.pdb____________ GGGP00000343764.6_192_p2.pdb____ 0.866667 0.070452     7750      630      546
    EEX51032_5j3b_p3.pdb____________ FFFP00000343764.6_192_p3.pdb____ NULL____ NULL____ ________ ________ ________
    EEX51032_p9.pdb_________________ RRRP00000436941.1_1_p1.pdb______ 0.807338 0.807338    11175    11175     9022
```

Desired output:

```
    EAZ51036 SSPP00000432782.1_1_p1.pdb______ 0.834183 0.812304    11175    11476     9322
    BBX51096 EEEP00000435284.1_1_p1.pdb______ 0.834183 0.812304    11175    11476     9322
    CCZ58032 NNNP00000343764.6_192_p1.pdb____ NULL____ NULL____ ________ ________ ________
    WWW25032 GGGP00000343764.6_192_p2.pdb____ 0.866667 0.070452     7750      630      546
    EEX51032 FFFP00000343764.6_192_p3.pdb____ NULL____ NULL____ ________ ________ ________
    EEX51032 RRRP00000436941.1_1_p1.pdb______ 0.807338 0.807338    11175    11175     9022
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try following awk once.

```
awk '{sub(/_.*_/,"",$1)} 1'  Input_file
```

**Explanation:** I am substituting here by using out of the box function named sub here. It works on `sub(regex_which_we_want_to_change_in_lines,new regex/variable,variable/line)`. So here I am giving `_.*_` in `$1`(first field)`,` means starting from `_.*`(which covers everything till _ with NULL. Then mentioning `1` means, `awk` works on method of `condition then action`, so here I am making condition TRUE and NOT mentioning any action, so by default print action will happen, which will print the current(edited/non-edited) line of Input_file.

Comment: done, was editing that only. Let me know if you have any queries on same.

Comment: Clear explanation. If suppose I have to do for 2nd column, how could specify the "column number " . Now if u see there is seven column in my input, so if i have to edit something in 4th column how can mention the column number. in awk we give -f4 in sed how how should i mention?

Answer (score 1):

with sed:

```
sed 's/_[^ ]*//' file
```

Comment: No it does not add anything. It just removes the first occurence of underscore `_` and every following character until the first space ` ` (the space remains).